# How to get the total of a dynamic variable from javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to get the total number of hours using the `time-in` and `time-out` input but the number of input is dynamic, it could ask multiple time-in and out so I made a dynamic id I call it `time_in-0`, `time_in-1`, etc. I need to get the time difference of `time_in-0` and `time_out-0` then get the number of hours let's say `hours-0` then all the hours will be added all together and show it to the `total` input
This is the javascript I came up with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".time").on("change", function() {
    var last_request_no = $('#total_request').val();

    for (var i = 0; i < last_request_no; i++) {
      var time_in = document.getElementById("time_in-" + i).value;
      var time_out = document.getElementById("time_out-" + i).value;
      var total = parseInt($("#time_out-" + i).val()) - parseInt($("#time_in-" + i).val());
    }

      console.log(total);
    $('#total').val(total);
  });
</script>
```

`.time` is the class of the time input
`#total` is the id of the total input which should show the total of all hours

Comment: Initiliase `var total` with `0` outside of the loop, and then add to it on every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity I made just concat values in In and Out.

```js
$(".time").on("keyup", function() {
  var index = $(this).attr("index")
  $("#diff" + index).val($("#timein" + index).val() + $("#timeout" + index).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Time-in <input id='timein0' index="0" class='time'>Time-out <input id='timeout0' index="0" class='time'>diff <input id='diff0'>
</div>
<div>
  Time-in <input id='timein1' index="1" class='time'>Time-out <input id='timeout1' index="1" class='time'>diff <input id='diff1'>
</div>
<div>
  Time-in <input id='timein2' index="2" class='time'>Time-out <input index="2" id='timeout2' class='time'>diff <input id='diff2'>
</div>
```